# La explicación del “alterado”

Tags: significado

> Una vez me encontré con un anciano sollozando, sentado en al borde de
>   un campo con la cara tumefacta y amoratada, **totalmente alterado por la
>   tristeza** que llevaba dentro.

No sé qué le había alterado por la tristeza / No sé en qué era lo que le había alterado.

**O, “alterado” = “inquietado”? No es “cambiado”?**

Por favor explicámelo.

Comment: Has mirado en el diccionário de la RAE? Perturbar, trastornar, inquietar. U. t. c. prnl. Creo que es mejor primero hacer un poco de investigacion antes de preguntar el sentido de las palabras aqui.

Comment: @Lambie sí. Pero no he entendido  mucho.

Comment: No creo que se debe traducir al inglés para explicar algo para una persona de idioma nativo chino (mandarín o cantonés). Porque se pone en juego tres idiomas y un lío mayor.

Comment: @Lambie Normalmente es cierto. Pero para mi es mejor que explique en idiomas que entiendo ya que para aprender un idioma nuevo, es muy difícil de comprenderlo. Aún no es muy correcto por las traducciones, ya muy útil.

Comment: alterado por algo no es cambiado. Es estar en un estado X, aqui tristeza.

Comment: La verdad es tu español no está nada mal, dado que tu idioma nativo es chino. Ojalá supiera un poco de tu idioma. :)

Comment: In english you have the same meaning "altered state" when a person behaves out of normal.

Comment: @Lambie todavía falta mucho. Sigo aprender por mi cuenta.

Comment: @roetnig ya veo. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Alterado means "altered" and in this case is used for someone who's physical or mind state is literally "altered", maybe you cannot understand why someone can be altered just because of sadness. I think the writer lacked the ability to transmit the feeling and that's why it is hard to understand why he was altered because of sadness.

Imagine someone who's destroyed not only by sadness but also sorrow, someone who's been crying a lot, out of himself, someone that the sadness has altered him.

I think something like this : http://www.cuded.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Man-crying.jpg